# Setting up a FreeBSD Server for packet filtering and routing

Tags: networking, architecture, bsd

I have heard the many goods of using FreeBSD in Networking over Linux with utils such as `pf` and `ipfw`
I currently have an multi tier application hosted on a vSphere environment with seperate servers for the application and database how can i Integrate BSD networking to my application ??

Answer (score 4):

Unless you already have a deep knowledge of BSD networking, your best bet is to install [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/) on a VM and use that for your routing/firewalling tasks.

pfSense is based on FreeBSD, and is a very, very capable purpose-built routing distribution.

Comment: I am doing this as a learning exercise .So is there any general guide to this

Comment: It's pretty easy to just follow your nose